# Best practice approach for many parameters

Tags: objective-c

I'm writing a signing up method which needs many parameters. Initially, I chose the below approach for my method.

```
// APPROACH #1
- (void)signUpWithInformation:(NSDictionary *)information
                      success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))success
                      failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure
{
    // ...

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"email": information[@"email"],
                                 @"new_password": information[@"password"],
                                 @"user_name": information[@"username"],
                                 @"sex": ([information[@"sex"] isEqualToNumber:@(EFTUserSexMale)]) ? @"M" : @"F",
                                 @"phone_nubmer": information[@"phoneNumber"],
                                 @"weight": information[@"weight"],
                                 @"height": information[@"height"],
                                 @"birthday": [formatter stringFromDate:information[@"birthday"]]};

    // ...
}
```

But I felt that this approach is some discomfort. Even though `information` gives me some flexibilities, it needs boxing and unboxing to store values to the dictionary.

So I thought the below approach.

```
// APPROACH #2
- (void)signUpWithEmail:(NSString *)email
               password:(NSString *)password
                   name:(NSString *)name
                    sex:(EFTUserSex)sex
            phoneNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber
                 weight:(double)weight
                 height:(double)height
               birthday:(NSDate *)birthday
                success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))success
                failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure
{
    // ...

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"email": email,
                                 @"new_password": password,
                                 @"user_name": username,
                                 @"sex": (sex == EFTUserSexMale) ? @"M" : @"F"
                                 @"phone_nubmer": phoneNumber,
                                 @"weight": weight,
                                 @"height": height,
                                 @"birthday": [formatter stringFromDate:birthday]};

    // ...
}
```

Because the objective-c has the named parameter structure, I think that this approach looks like dictionary and there is no needs for boxing and unboxing.

However, I can't decide which approach is the best. Maybe there are another good approaches?

Comment: How about wrapping all that related information in a class, and passing a single instance of that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What would be easier is to abstract all of this data into a custom model class. For example, you could create an ETFUser class who has properties corresponding to all of the keys in your dictionary. This is a better object-oriented design (relating similar data in a class, rather than relating data as parameters, or as values in a dictionary) and will give you compile-time checking that all of the provided values are the correct type, which is not the case when putting everything in to a dictionary. Using a dictionary also would require you to document all of the proper keys and types to be used, but when using a model class, it is immediately apparent what data is required and what type it should be.

So you would have a class, EFTUser with this interface:

```
@interface ETFUser : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *newPassword;
@property (nonatomic) EFTUserSex sex;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *phoneNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *weight;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *height;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *birthday;

@end
```

Now, you may still need to generate a dictionary version of this data, in order to pass as body params to a network request. In that case, now you have a perfect place to put this code! Add a `- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryRepresentation` method to your new `EFTUser` class that will generate a properly formatted dictionary to pass to network requests. This prevents that code from being duplicated in any place you need to make a request with user data.

The method in your example can now be simplified to:

```
- (void)signUpWithUser:(EFTUser *)user
                  success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))success
                  failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = [user dictionaryRepresentation];

    //...
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer just after you, but your method is cleaner than mine, I removed my post. :)

Comment: +1 for "types to be used" *and* dictionaryRepresentation method

Comment: Then, does `signUpWithUser:success:failure:` method reside in the `EFTUser` class?

Comment: no, that is the refactored signature of the method you are defining in your example. Model classes should not be responsible for handling their own network calls, only for expressing the data that belongs to that model. Other classes will use the EFTUser class to make network calls.